# PHP form not validating with functions

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<title>Guestbook</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<?php



function check($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr){
$userErr = $emailErr = $noteErr = "";
$user = $email = $note = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["user"])) 
        $userErr = "Please fill out a name.";
    else 
        $user = $_POST["user"];

    if (empty($_POST["email"]))  
        $emailErr = "Please fill out an email.";
    else 
        $email = $_POST["email"];

    if (empty($_POST["note"]))  
        $noteErr = "Please give us your comments.";
    else 
        $note= $_POST["note"];



}

    if ($userErr=="" or $emailErr=="" or $noteErr=="")
        display($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr);
        else
        displayResult($user, $email, $note);

}

function display($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Please Sign Our Guestbook</h2>
<form method="post" action="mock.php"> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="user" value=""  /><span class="error"><br> $userErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="email" value=""  /><span class="error"><br> $emailErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Comments: </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="note"></textarea><span class="error"><br> $noteErr</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

function displayResult($user, $email, $note){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Your Input:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>$user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Email: </td><td>$email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valgin="top">Comments: </td><td>$note</td>
</tr>
</table>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}



if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

    check($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr);
else
    display($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr);

?>



</body>
</html>
```

I already know the error resides in my functions and or the logic I have to execute them. But I'm really unsure where exactly to go from here. Everything worked very well before I implemented the functions. Granted, I am a novice to this. When the submit button is pressed no data is sent to the displayResult() page and my error messages don't pop up whenever the form is submitted completely blank. Here's my current page: http://awsymposium.com/mock.php and the end product should look and operate similar to this: http://professorgustin.com/dpr206/guestbook/guestbookonescript.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated a little bit your code. I also strongly recomand that you also use a javascript validation for your fields.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<title>Guestbook</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<?php



function check($user, $email, $note){
$userErr = $emailErr = $noteErr = "";

    if ($user=="") 
        $userErr = "Please fill out a name.";

    else if ($email=="")  
        $emailErr = "Please fill out an email.";

    else if ($note=="")  
        $noteErr = "Please give us your comments.";

    if (($userErr !="") || ($emailErr !="") || ($noteErr !=""))
        display($user, $email, $note, $userErr, $emailErr, $noteErr);
    if(($userErr =="") && ($emailErr =="") && ($noteErr ==""))
        displayResult($user, $email, $note);

}

function display($user=null, $email=null, $note=null, $userErr=null, $emailErr=null, $noteErr=null){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Please Sign Our Guestbook</h2>
<form method="POST" action="test321.php"> 
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="user" value="$user"  /><span class="error"><br> $userErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" size="34" name="email" value="$email"  /><span class="error"><br> $emailErr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Comments: </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="note">$note</textarea><span class="error"><br> $noteErr</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}

function displayResult($user, $email, $note){
print<<<TABLE_BLOCK
<h2>Your Input:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>$user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Email: </td><td>$email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valgin="top">Comments: </td><td>$note</td>
</tr>
</table>
TABLE_BLOCK;
}



if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

    check($_POST['user'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['note']);
else
    display();

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That actually worked out really well. I really appreciate your help. It's sort of extra, but the only thing that did seem off was that the error messages ("You did not fill in an email"...etc) only pop up one at a time, and not simultaneously if multiple fields are submitted blank. Any way to fix that? Either way, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, never mind. I'm stupid. I just got rid of the else in the "else if" statements. I think I'm good now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You can replace the `else if` from `check` function with just `if`. That should solve it.